# Finding number of Points within Cluster by different sizes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to figure out how many points are within a pre-determined cluster size. For instance, I can create this map

[image]

I can see there are a few clusters and I can create a heatmap to illustrate the density. However, I'm trying to figure out how to set a cluster with a radius of 5, 10, and 20 miles and count how many points are within those cluster.

Do you know how to implement this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Qgis Marker Cluster](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QgisMarkerCluster/) plugin that takes point layers and creates clusters by distance. The plugin is marked as experimental , so you need to go to ‘Settings’ and check the box that has an option ‘Show also experimental plugins’, if you didn't do that already.

Here is another link about [USING THE QGIS MARKERCLUSTER PLUGIN TO CREATE CLUSTER MAPS](https://mapsnigeriainitiative.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/using-the-qgis-markercluster-plugin-to-create-cluster-maps/) that gives you an overview about the plugin.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what is the measurement of the distance clusters? For instance, what does it mean to have a cluster distance of 0.0005, I'm trying to make some sense of this

Comment: It means that your data is in WGS84 or geographic in general, and the 0.0005 is the distance in decimal degree. You need to convert your data in projection that uses meter as unit such as UTM, or any other projection that suites your needs.